# Google_play_services error message

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I followed instructions to install google_play_services in Eclipse, but although everything looks right, including Library dependencies, project just won't compile.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: and why won't it compile? is there any exception or something?

Comment: It says:Archive for required library: '/google-play-services_lib/.classpath' in project ‘….’ cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  Build path Build Path Problem

Comment: I would like to add a screenshot showing the problem in Eclipse, but I am probably not allowed to do so... Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

As can be seen, google_play_services_lib is present, but Eclipse says it can't be read or is not a Zip file.

I am somewhat lost about this.